# function is undefined

Tags: javascript

im struggling with a script where a method/object returns `undefined`

```
var Lang = new function(){
    this.get = function(str, trans){
        if(TRANSLATE[str]){
            var str = TRANSLATE[str][LANG];
            if(count_obj(trans) > 0){
                for(var key in trans){
                    str = str.replace('%'+key+'%', trans[key]);
                }
            }

            return str;
        }
    };
};

function Language(){
    this.tbl_list = null;

    this.append = function(string, obj, index){
        var row = $('<tr></tr>')
            .append('<td class="list_row">'+js2txt(string)+'</td>');

        for(var key in obj){
            row.append('<td class="list_row">'+js2txt(obj[key])+'</td>');
        }
        var td = $('<td class="list_row"></td>').appendTo(row);
        //var inp_edit = $('<input type="button" value="'+Lang.get('BTN_EDIT')+'" />');
        alert(Lang.get);
        List.append_row(row, this.tbl_list, index);
    };
};
alert(Lang.get);
```

inside the Language object `Lang.get` returns undefined, but outside it returns the function!?

Comment: Not enough context to understand what's going on.

Comment: how do you know what is `inside` and what is `outside`?

Comment: Is there a variable scoping issue? perhaps try specifying it as a global? `var window.Lang = Lang;` (above the function) and then in the function change it to `window.Lang.get`

Comment: Are you showing the whole code? Is `Lang` an instance of `Language`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
> var Lang = new function(){
>     this.get = function(str, trans){
>         if(TRANSLATE[str]){
>             var str = TRANSLATE[str][LANG];
>             if(count_obj(trans) > 0){
>                 for(var key in trans){
>                     str = str.replace('%'+key+'%', trans[key]);
>                 }
>             }
>             return str;
>         }
>     }; };
```

I don't see a reason for using new above, it's just a waste of resources. Since Lang doesn't seem to be called as a constructor, it should, by convention, start with a lower case letter. Why not:

```
var lang = {
    get: function(str, trans) {
        // function body
    }
};
```

.

```
> function Language(){
>     this.tbl_list = null;
> 
>     this.append = function(string, obj, index){
>     /* snip */
>         alert(Lang.get);
>     /* snip */
>     }; };


alert(Lang.get);  // shows source of Lang.get
```

> inside the Language object Lang.get returns undefined, but outside it returns the function!?

How are you calling it? It appears to be a constructor, so:

```
var x = new Language();  // Create instance lf Language
x.append();  // Shows Lang.get
```

Which is the same result as calling `Language` as a function. What is the issue?

Also, the jQuery stuff seems to be very inefficient. You might want to work on that. e.g.

```
> var row = $('<tr></tr>')
>             .append('<td class="list_row">'+js2txt(string)+'</td>');
```

would be much better as:

```
var row = $('<tr><td class="list_row">'+js2txt(string)+'</td></tr>');
```

Or even better would be to create a single row with the structure you want, clone it for each row, then just replace the content of the cell.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is where you went wrong:

```
var Lang = new function(){
```

Don't use `new` when assigning a function to a variable. Do this:

```
var Lang = function(){
```

Comment: or it's a singleton and should be `var Lang = new (function(){ ... });`

Answer (score 0):

The `Language` function definition and initialization are hoisted above the `var Lang` initialization.  Is it possible that `Language` is being called before the initializer for `Lang` is reached?

Comment: no.. the Lang is initialized first.. the code is coming in the same order as pasted here

Comment: the alert with Lang.get outside the Language object returns the funtion perfectly

Comment: @clarkk.  I wasn't asking which is initialized first.   Language is definitely initialized first.  Try running `alert(f()); var x = 42; function f() { return "x=" + x; }` and it will alert `x=undefined` instead of reporting an error because `f` is initialized first, then `f` is called, then `x` is initialized.

Comment: @clarkk What I was asking is whether `Language` is called before `var Lang` appears in the program text.  There's no call to `Language` in your code.